# Как правильно составить запрос 1с?

Tags: 1с

Имеется следующий код:

```
Запрос.Текст =
"ВЫБРАТЬ                                                        
|   ЦеныНоменклатурыСрезПоследних.ВидЦены КАК ВидЦены,
|   ЦеныНоменклатурыСрезПоследних.Номенклатура КАК Номенклатура, 
|   ЦеныНоменклатурыСрезПоследних.Цена КАК Цена
|ИЗ
|   РегистрСведений.ЦеныНоменклатуры.СрезПоследних(
|           ,) КАК ЦеныНоменклатурыСрезПоследних";
```

как добавить **Количество** чтобы также вышло количество данной Номенклатуры (товара)?

Comment: Сформулируйте подробнее, что именно вам нужно. В регистре цен данных о количестве нет.

Answer (score 0):

Для получение остатков, должны еще быть в конфигурации регистры накопления. "ТоварыНаСкладах" допустим. Также учет по складам обычно ведется по складам. если взять условие что вам нужен количество по всем складам, то выглядить запрос будет так :

```
Запрос.Текст =
"ВЫБРАТЬ
|   ЦеныНоменклатурыСрезПоследних.ВидЦены КАК ВидЦены,
|   ЦеныНоменклатурыСрезПоследних.Номенклатура КАК Номенклатура,
|   ЦеныНоменклатурыСрезПоследних.Цена КАК Цена,
|   ЕСТЬNULL(ТоварыНаСкладахОстатки.ВНаличииОстаток, 0) КАК Количество
|ИЗ
|   РегистрСведений.ЦеныНоменклатуры.СрезПоследних(, ) КАК ЦеныНоменклатурыСрезПоследних
|       ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрНакопления.ТоварыНаСкладах.Остатки КАК ТоварыНаСкладахОстатки
|       ПО ЦеныНоменклатурыСрезПоследних.Номенклатура = ТоварыНаСкладахОстатки.Номенклатура
|           И ЦеныНоменклатурыСрезПоследних.Характеристика = ТоварыНаСкладахОстатки.Характеристика";
```

Comment: А как к запросу добавить ИД товара?